# how to get the class' members from a class file

Tags: java, bytecode

if there is a class file called "demo.class",
is it possible to analysis the file without run it by VM,and get
its members' message, such as attributes' name,methods' name and fields' type?

if it do,please give me any advice for how to start my work,thank you!

Comment: That really depends on how it was compiled. Most IDEs include human readable names, but highly optimizing compilers may just skip them, as they're not necessary in the bytecode. If that was done, you only get nameless functions - you can still inspect them, but may have a hard time figuring out there meaning

Comment: thank you very much.The analysis is useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reflection

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classMembers.html

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Member;
import static java.lang.System.out;

enum ClassMember { CONSTRUCTOR, FIELD, METHOD, CLASS, ALL }

public class ClassSpy {
    public static void main(String... args) {
    try {
        Class<?> c = Class.forName(args[0]);
        out.format("Class:%n  %s%n%n", c.getCanonicalName());

        Package p = c.getPackage();
        out.format("Package:%n  %s%n%n",
               (p != null ? p.getName() : "-- No Package --"));

        for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
        switch (ClassMember.valueOf(args[i])) {
        case CONSTRUCTOR:
            printMembers(c.getConstructors(), "Constructor");
            break;
        case FIELD:
            printMembers(c.getFields(), "Fields");
            break;
        case METHOD:
            printMembers(c.getMethods(), "Methods");
            break;
        case CLASS:
            printClasses(c);
            break;
        case ALL:
            printMembers(c.getConstructors(), "Constuctors");
            printMembers(c.getFields(), "Fields");
            printMembers(c.getMethods(), "Methods");
            printClasses(c);
            break;
        default:
            assert false;
        }
        }

        // production code should handle these exceptions more gracefully
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    private static void printMembers(Member[] mbrs, String s) {
    out.format("%s:%n", s);
    for (Member mbr : mbrs) {
        if (mbr instanceof Field)
        out.format("  %s%n", ((Field)mbr).toGenericString());
        else if (mbr instanceof Constructor)
        out.format("  %s%n", ((Constructor)mbr).toGenericString());
        else if (mbr instanceof Method)
        out.format("  %s%n", ((Method)mbr).toGenericString());
    }
    if (mbrs.length == 0)
        out.format("  -- No %s --%n", s);
    out.format("%n");
    }

    private static void printClasses(Class<?> c) {
    out.format("Classes:%n");
    Class<?>[] clss = c.getClasses();
    for (Class<?> cls : clss)
        out.format("  %s%n", cls.getCanonicalName());
    if (clss.length == 0)
        out.format("  -- No member interfaces, classes, or enums --%n");
    out.format("%n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have the class file (and can't load it because it's not on the classpath or you don't want to load it), you can inspect it using [Apache Commons Byte Code Engineering Library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/)

```
ClassParser parser=new ClassParser(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/my/package/MyClass.class"), "MyClass.class");
JavaClass javaClass=parser.parse();
javaClass.getMethods(); // Get whatever info you need
```

Comment: thank you very much,You must be a master?Can I make another question--In fact, I'm just a junior student,the most difficult point of my work is to anylyze the java source code and get the message of the class.However I'm unable to design a  syntactic analyzer and turn to analyze its class file.Now whether there is any way to get the message  from the source code directorily?Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use Java disassembler 'javap command'

suppose  your class files are located in bin folder & path is 
"D:\dev\jdk_1.06\bin" 
then 
1.open command prompt 
2.change directory to above mentioned path.
3.type java javaclassfilename
   for example: for hello.class
   use command javap hello